# Fetch remote changes with out changing branches in SourceTree

Tags: git, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree, git-fetch

I have a local branch but someone pushed changes to another branch. I can see there are changes because the Source tree UI tells me. See red circles below.

[image]

I know it's not hard to switch branches then pull but using the CLI I can get those remote changes with out switching branches like this.

`git fetch origin <branch>:<branch>`

So if I wanted to get the changes from develop I run this in the CLI.

`git fetch origin develop:develop`

How can I do this in source tree with out going to the CLI.